# Как создать рекурсивный запрос к БД с помощью Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, у меня есть проблема. Есть таблица категорий, которая выглядит так:
[image: Таблица категорий]

Задача при выборе категории высшей иерархии подтянуть все его подкатегории - создать коллекцию категорий дерева. 
Вопрос такой: как реализовать такую задачу с помощью Entity Framework? Возможно ли сделать это одним запросом к БД?

За любую помощь буду признателен)

Comment: join? [15 символов]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Entity Framework* не умеет в рекурсивные запросы. Но проблему решить можно.

**Вариант 1:**

Сделать *view* на основе рекурсивного запроса на SQL используя `WITH CTE`. После чего в коде вызывать получение данных из этой вью.

Примерный код SQL:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Subcategories] 
AS 
WITH    cte ( CategoryID, SubcatID) 
          AS ( SELECT   Id AS SubcatID, 
                        RootId as CategoryID
               FROM     dbo.TableName
               UNION ALL 
               SELECT   e.Id AS SubcatID, 
                        cte.Id AS CategoryID
               FROM     cte 
                        INNER JOIN dbo.TableName AS e ON e.RootId = cte.Id )
```

**Вариант 2:**

Сделать простой отдельный рекурсивный метод в коде для получения дочерних EF-объектов:

```
List<Category> GoDownRecursive(int categoryId) 
{
    var res = new List<Category>();

    foreach(var subcategory in DbContext.Cateogires.Where(c => c.RootId == categoryId)
    {
        res.Add(subcategory);
        res.AddRange(GoDownRecursive(subcategory.Id));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Запросов к базе будет больше, но если вложенность небольшая и запрос не самый частый, то вариант приемлимый. При желании полученные деревья можно кэшировать.

Comment: Если использовать вариант 1,  то выдаёт сообщение об ошибке: "Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции ")".". Как это исправить, не подскажете?

Comment: @unitreid исправил запрос. Учтите, что запрос возвращает только первый уровень подкатегорий. Чтобы вернуть из view результат, нужно сравнить categoryId с Id выбранной категории.

Answer (score 2):

Entity прекрасно работает с хранимыми процедурами на стороне SQL - попробуйте их!

**Плюсы:** 
Потенциальный выигрыш в производительности, потому что все промежуточные выборки происходят на стороне SQL.

**Минусы:**
 Дополнительное "распыление" бизнес-логики.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, почему бы не сделать так: в entity для категории завести список подкатегорий, и отключить для них lazy loading?

[Здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) описаны методы отключения lazy loading, как полностью, так и для конкретных свойств или вообще лишь на одну операцию.

Скорее всего, вам подойдёт просто

```
var categories = context.Categories.Include("SubCategories").ToList();
```

Comment: Список подкатегорий будет сложно держать в актуальном виде. Хотелось бы более динамический вариант.

Comment: Эээ... Почему сложно? В каком flow вы видите проблему?